# Unity3D Vector Math Problem for adjusting Aim using an IK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically I'm using an Ik system in Unity and i want my Gun to aim at the mouse.
The problem is that I can only control The position of the IK bone which is not where the bullet will come from, There's a Gun object that is a child of the IK bone and it rotates with it.
What I want to do is position the IK in a way so that the FirePoint(where the bullet will come out) is always rotated towards the mouse.

Here's an image to better visualize the problem
[image: Aim Adjustement]

Comment: Do you have a gameobject or anything at the `firePoint`? From the diagram it looks like there is one at `firePoint` with its local Right (red axis) pointing out of the gun. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the game object is called firePoint, but i can not control its position, only the ik bone.and it's a child of the gun.

Comment: And, just to confirm - it's **right** direction is pointing toward the direction of the gun fire? This is highly unusual for a 3d game and the question does not really indicate if this is a 2d or 3d game.

Comment: It is in 2D, yes, and it's right direction rotates with the gun. and the gun it self rotates depending on the ik.

Comment: So if the gun is pointing to the left- it still shoots in the local right direction? Adding answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation in comments

```
// currentFirePoint and currentIKPoint are the transform of the fire Point and the 
// world position of IK Point at some given moment. 
// aimOrign and mousePosInWorldSpace are world space positions of the aim Origin and 
// mouse position that produce the desired IK point.
Vector3 GetNewIKPoint(Transform currentFirePoint, Vector3 currentIKPoint,
        Vector3 aimOrigin, Vector3 mousePosInWorldSpace)
{
    float firePointRange = aimOriginToCurrentFP.magnitude;

    //Find the local position of IK in Fire Point space
    Vector3 curFirePointToIK = currentIKPoint - currentFirePoint;
    Vector3 localFirePointToIK = currentFirePoint.InverseTransformVector(
            curFirePointToIK);

    // Stuff above this point could be done once and cached, 
    // assuming things like the offset or fire point range don't change.
    
    // Determine where the new fire point will be
    Vector3 newFireDirection = (mousePosInWorldSpace - aimOrigin).normalized;
    Vector3 newFirePoint = firePointRange * newFireDirection;

    // Find rotation such that local right = newFireDirection
    // and local up is closer to Vector3.up than Vector3.down

    // find local forward
    Vector3 newFPLocalForward = Vector3.Cross(newFireDirection, Vector3.up);
    // find local up
    Vector3 newFPLocalUp = Vector3.Cross(newFPLocalForward, newFireDirection);
    Quaternion newFPRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newFPLocalForward, 
            newFPLocalUp);

    // Apply that rotation to the local position of IK to find the world space offset. 
    Vector3 newFirePointToIK = newFPRotation * localFirePointToIK;

    // Add to fire point to get world space position
    return newFirePoint + newFirePointToIK;
}
```

This same logic could be applied to 3D space too, but be sure to change the calculation of `newFPRotation` accordingly.